# Opening an executable

Tags: php, exec, executable

I have this code to open an executable file:

```
exec("C:/Users/Affex/Desktop/Blockland/".$session->username."/".$session->username.".exe        ptlaaxobimwroe -dedicated");
```

It opens the file that I want it to open but it keeps loading the page untill the php.ini kicks in with the max execution time.

I'm trying to setup a game panel for my free hosting service, BIOHazardHosting.co.uk, We have everything else sorted but this.

Comment: We also have a login system so it does open the right file

Comment: There's an edit button for editing the question

Comment: I'm not so sure you should be managing process (starting, stopping, etc) from php.  That sounds like the job for SSH or cron.

Answer (score 6):

Try add putting a `start` in the beginning of the command:

```
exec("start C:/Users/Affex/Desktop/Blockland/".$session->username."/".$session->username.".exe        ptlaaxobimwroe -dedicated");
```

---

As a side note in linux you would append an `&` to the end of the command to achieve the same result:

```
exec("/Users/Affex/Desktop/Blockland/".$session->username."/".$session->username.".exe        ptlaaxobimwroe -dedicated &");
```

Comment: Add the `/B` flag if you want the process to run in the background. For example: `exec("start /B C:/Users ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the limit in the script:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```